# How to effectively perform sorting and filters in an online shop?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'd like to create an online shop that has around 10,000 products with sorting and filters where pricing and availability change dynamically in real-time (every minute, hour or day).

I have a MySQL database called "mainDatabase" set up with a table named "products".

Since the database is around 30MB (excluding pictures) I can't just download all the products and do the processing client-side.

How do I sort the products and then return the first 25-100?

I can't have them pre-sorted because prices change constantly.

Comment: I feel like datatables is the go to for most people. https://datatables.net/

Comment: Get the MySQL to do it. Search for ORDER BY and LIMIT.

Comment: Insure the database table is [indexed](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ricksrots#indexing) by the way people select and sort from it.

Comment: Isn't it inefficient to sort a database with 10,000 items in SQL whenever a user asks for something?

Comment: I mean on the server side.

Comment: @vulkan If that's the requirement, use an index. Most searches like this will be filtered for product type or manufacturer or whatever, so you'd only be sorting a subset of the total database. It sounds to me like you don't have the experience to make a good job of this. Have you thought about [Shopify](https://www.shopify.com/)